# Clear file upload form doesn't work after file upload succeeded with dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, image-uploading, dropzone.js, dropzone

My goal is to upload a bunch of pictures to the server and then clear the form if the upload process has been finished successfully. However `successmultiple` event doesn't fire at all.

I tried to do that in three different ways by locating call for `removeAllFiles()` in different places in code: inside and outside of `init` and as a separate event.
But no success.

**Full code snippet:**

```
<form ref='uploadForm'
   id='uploadForm'
   action='/file-upload'
   method='post'
   class="dropzone"
   encType="multipart/form-data" name="sampleFile">
</form>

<script>
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

      Dropzone.options.uploadForm = {
         autoProcessQueue: false,
         addRemoveLinks: true,
         acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
         resizeWidth: 800,
         resizeMimeType: 'image/jpeg',
         maxFiles: 3,

         init: function () {
            var submitButton = document.getElementById('addItem-btn')
                myDropzone = this;

            submitButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
               var item_id = 'i_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 12);

               getAdditionalItem(undefined, function (result) {
                  if (result === undefined) {
                     console.log("Callback failed...");
                  }
                  else {
                     addNewItem(result[0], result[1], item_id);
                  }
               });

               myDropzone.on('sending', function (file, xhr, uploadForm) {
                  uploadForm.append('user_id', localStorage.getItem("user_id")),
                  uploadForm.append('item_id', item_id)
               });

               myDropzone.processQueue();

               myDropzone.on("successmultiple", function () {
                  alert("Attempt #1: All pics uploaded");
                  myDropzone.removeAllFiles();
               });
            });

            myDropzone.on("successmultiple", function () {
               alert("Attempt #2: All pics uploaded");
               myDropzone.removeAllFiles();
            });
         },

         successmultiple: function () {
            alert("Attempt #3: All pics uploaded");
            myDropzone.removeAllFiles();
         }
      }
   });
</script>
```

When I execute this code all pictures are uploaded, but no alert is fired and the dropzone form is not being cleaned.

I also tried to use a `queuecomplete` event with `removeAllFiles()`, but there is no result as well.

Comment: Did you set `uploadMultiple: true` ?

Comment: RAM, initially I didn't, but I've set it now as you suggested. Unfortunately no positive result.

Comment: Have you tried to handle an `error` event to be sure the error doesn't occur? Also I see a suspicious piece of code `getAdditionalItem Props...`. Doesn't it cause the error?